# Rank top 10 but sort alphabetically then by rank. SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table for a county that holds testing stats for all the schools in that county. Im trying to display the top 10 ranking schools where the difference between the writing and reading scores are the greatest

```
select * 
    from 
        (select  SchoolName, WriPassingPer, ReaPassingPer, 
        (WriPassingPer - WriPassingPer) as Difference, dense_rank() over 
                (order by ABS(WriPassingPer - WriPassingPer) desc) as rnk from Pima) 
    where rnk <= 10;
```

I want it to look like

```
Rank | School Name | Writing Score | Reading Score | Difference
```

But at the moment it's just listing every single school in the county with a rank of either 1 or 2. There are 283 schools in the county

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are computing `WriPassingPer - WriPassingPer` instead of `WriPassingPer - ReaPassingPer` or something like that...

Comment: Omg. Thank you. I am ashamed

Comment: Well, don't be, we 've all been there (some of us still are from time to time!)

Comment: Follow up question. How do I ignore all null values for WriPassingPer and ReaPassingPer?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by ignore?